# Is there an Ubuntu tablet edition?

Tags: tablet, ipad, ubuntu-touch

Is there a tablet version of Ubuntu?  Will it run on the iPad or motion LE1600?

Answer (score 5):

There was speculation on the 18th of February 2013 about HTC releasing a tablet that runs the Ubuntu OS. Information about this can be found in the following sites:

- [Gotta Be Mobile](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/02/19/will-htc-introduce-an-ubuntu-tablet-today/)
- [OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-gearing-up-for-tablet-announcement-tomorrow)
- [Slashdot](http://news.slashdot.org/story/13/02/18/2236218/canonical-announcing-ubuntu-tablet-tomorrow)

The Ubuntu site on the same day offered a countdown that would end on February 19th 2013. The countdown when finished showed the following video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h384z7Ph0gU

Apart from the information provided above, you can also read the following link for more information regarding Tablets: http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/tablet

One thing we can see from the information here is the hardware requirements for Tablets:

[image]

Regarding the installation of Ubuntu (Or any other Distro for that matter), please see my answer here: [How can I install Ubuntu on an iPad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6263/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-ipad?rq=1)

I also recommend reading this question: [What is Ubuntu Touch (Ubuntu for Phones)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

**UPDATE Feb 21 2013** - [The Ubuntu Phone, Tablet Developer Preview has been released](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMwODI)

You can also visit the official [Touch site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch)

Comment: What does it mean "full desktop convergence"?

Comment: @leonardvertighel that it will do the following: Offer a look that when connected to a TV will still look the same and that this same look (Resolution, Size or Distance between all objects shown if you will) will look the same when connected to a monitor. Look at the video I provided and go to the time 2:42 in the video. That is desktop convergence right there.