# Ubuntu for tablets has been announced: is it related to HTC One's announcement?

Tags: tablet

Won't I be able to download and install Ubuntu on other tablets like Samsung Galaxy Tab or Micromax Funbook? If I can, what was the relation between the timing sync between [HTC](http://htc.com) and [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/)?

**EDIT:** My question is mainly to clarify the role of HTC behind the release of Ubuntu for tablets. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support?lq=1) addresses similar issues about Ubuntu for phone. Though the OS's are the same, its the difference in interface that distinguishes both of them.

Comment: Were you not going to install Ubuntu on a bunch of tablets? That takes some skill. You might want to review [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support) before proceeding.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Don't know how did you infer I was going to install Ubuntu on a **bunch** of tablets. Though the OS for phones and tablets are the same, the interface of each of them are tailored made for themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was no relation between both companies (in relation to the timing sync issue). They just happened to launch at the same date and both decided to use the same tactic (A countdown timer).

At the end, HTC launched their new and shiny **HTC One** and Ubuntu launched a video tour of Ubuntu for Tablets.

I would point you to the following links:

[What is Ubuntu Touch (Ubuntu for Phones)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it/235324#235324)

[Is there an Ubuntu tablet edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70475/is-there-an-ubuntu-tablet-edition)

Comment: That wa naive of me. I thought it was a kind of joint venture :P

Comment: heck even the code they used for the timer was apparently the same :p

Comment: Why yes it was ^^. I for one was thinking of an "Ubuntu One" HTC model. But nope. Only HTC ;(.