# Will there be x86 builds of Ubuntu Tablet / Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

While there is plenty of buzz for Ubuntu Touch / Ubuntu Phone builds for Nexuses, are there any images (if at all) coming for the normal x86 platform. I am particularly interested in the Ubuntu Tablet developer images. What is the official Ubuntu response regarding this platform?

Comment: Just wait a few more days to find out!

Comment: x86 is not a normal platform, at least as far as phones and tablets are concerned. As for an official response, contact Canonical, and ask.

Comment: Information here http://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it and http://askubuntu.com/questions/70475/is-there-an-ubuntu-tablet-edition?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

As per the hardware requirements on the [OEM partner information page](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/tablet/partner) for tablets, there will almost certainly be an x86 version available.