# Can Ubuntu Touch be installed on a iPad one

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have an iPad one and would simply like to know if Ubuntu touch can be installed on it and where I can find information on how to do this, I have done many searches on Utube and google! so far nada.

Please help if you can.
Best regards Susan.

Comment: That's easy: No, it cannot.

Comment: you cant https://askubuntu.com/questions/6263/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-ipad and ubuntu touch is no longer maintained so forget about it https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch, unless you want to use ubports but again you cant

Comment: @Lynob post that as an answer, short and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu touch is [no longer maintained](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch), and [it won't work on IPads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6263/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-ipad) anyway. [Ubports](https://ubports.com/page/get-ubuntu-touch) are developing ubuntu touch now, IPads is not on their list of supported devices either.